# Pending Intent is not opening activity

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development. I'm able to see the ticker message "Did you reach to office", but when I click it, it's not opening my main activity.

Below is my code:

```
private class ViewUpdater implements Runnable{
  private Context contextFromView;
  public ViewUpdater(Context context) {
    this.contextFromView = context;
  }
  @Override
  public void run() {
    CancelNotification(contextFromView, notificationId);
    Random r=  new Random();
    notificationId =r.nextInt();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(),1000,intent,0);
    String body = "congratulations you made it today";
    String title = "Office reached";
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
      new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
      .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_go)
      .setContentTitle(title)
      .setTicker("Did you reach office?")
      .setContentText(body);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    nm.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 200000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give an `Intent` to start the right Activity when creating your `PendingIntent`. Also the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is necessary because you'll start the Activity outside the context of an existing Activity (source: [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)).

```
Intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(),1000,intent,0);
```